# Prove if the following vectors are orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Prove:

If **u** * **v** = 0 and |**u**||**v**| = 1, then it form an orthonormal set.

To prove the set is orthonormal set, I must prove that |**u**| = |**v**| = 1,
But i’m stock, I was wondering if anyone can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:** in ${\mathbb R}^2$ take
$$
x = (2,0), \qquad y=(0,{1\over2})
$$
Both of your conditions are satisfied, yet these vectors do not form an orthonormal set.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Counterexample: $u = (2,0)$ and $v=(0,1/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily true |**u**|=1/|**v**| is also OK